# return string outside of return function

Tags: python

```
for resultparameter in urine_dict ['patientresultslist']:
    #start by assigning each of the pieces of daa within parameter line
    resulparalist = resultparameter.split(';')
    reportstring = reportstring + vet.setwidth(resultparalist[0], 8) + lineterm + lineterm
    vert.setwidth(resultparalist[1[,10) + vet.setwidth(resultpatientlist)
    if config['Bargraph'].lower() == 'yes':
        reportstring = reporttring + vet.bargraph(resultparameterlist)

    return reportstring
```

when I click to run it gives me an error to say the return is outside of function anyone can tell where I am making this error.

Comment: because there is no function? function is defines using `def` in python

Comment: Show your actual indentation and any function defintion

Comment: Did you mean to `print(reportstring)`?

Comment: there were no errors with this code up until now, so i dont know what happened for it to give me an error, also i have been having alot of issues with indentation, when i indent it it says its an error, so when i take indentation off its no longer an error, and yes i guess i want it to print the string it receives

Comment: Simply use `print reportstring` or `print(reportstring)`, then, if you're not defining a function.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are showing us only part of your code, that is because a `return` statement can only be used in a function, it simply won't work with `if` statements. Here's an example on how it works in a function. Also, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python).

```
def return_example():
    return 'Hello, world!'

returned_string = return_example()
print(returned_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a function:

```
def my_function(...):
    for resultparameter in urine_dict ['patientresultslist']:
    #start by assigning each of the pieces of daa within parameter line
    resulparalist = resultparameter.split(';')
    reportstring = reportstring + vet.setwidth(resultparalist[0], 8) + lineterm + lineterm
    vert.setwidth(resultparalist[1[,10) + vet.setwidth(resultpatientlist)
    if config['Bargraph'].lower() == 'yes':
       reportstring = reporttring + vet.bargraph(resultparameterlist)

    return reportstring
```

And then, call it:

```
result = my_function(...)
print(result)
```